# how to change the font of a pagertitlestrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

```
Typeface xyz=Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/xyz.ttf");
(TextView)abc.setTypeface(xyz);
```

This is how you create and set a custom typeface.

I need to set the typeface/font of a `pagertitlestrip` but there is no `.setTypeFace` function for `pagertitlestrip`. Does anyone know how I can do that anyway?

Answer (score 9):

The `PagerTitleStrip` is actually extends `ViewGroup`, so you can just subclass it and iterate through each of its children to find the views that need their font to be changed:

```
public class CustomFontPagerTitleStrip extends PagerTitleStrip {
    public CustomFontPagerTitleStrip(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomFontPagerTitleStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/xyz.ttf");
        for (int i=0; i<this.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (this.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView)this.getChildAt(i)).setTypeface(tf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only downside is that it prevents Eclipse from being able to display your layout.

Comment: User Gábor suggests: use `if (!isInEditMode())` to make sure it doesn't run in Eclipse.

Comment: hi, i get a class cast exception when i try to link it with my xml view.

Comment: jburns20, this is very old and I am not sure if that's relevant but you can always use isInEditMode() check in the constructor to solve the "preview" issues

Answer (score 1):

if it's a custom font put it in asset folder and change it like this.

```
public class WeeklyFragment extends Fragment{


PagerTitleStrip _Title;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekly_fragment, container, false);                   
    _Title = (PagerTitleStrip)rootView.findViewById(R.id.__Weekly_pager_title_strip);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "your font.ttf"); 

    for (int counter = 0 ; counter<_Title.getChildCount(); counter++) {

        if (_Title.getChildAt(counter) instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView)_Title.getChildAt(counter)).setTypeface(font);
            ((TextView)_Title.getChildAt(counter)).setTextSize(25);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I *think* `ViewPager` supports `android:textAppearance`, you can't set the typeface that way either.

You are probably best served copying the `PagerTitleStrip` code (in your SDK or [available online](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.java)), refactor your fork into your own package, and modify it to suit. Or, see if the ViewPagerIndicator library has one that you like that allows you to configure the typeface.