# Android: Change Font in PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to do this? The PagerTitleStrip class doesn't have a .setTypeface method or anything of the sort so I'm a bit stumped.

Another response I found suggested: 
`You are probably best served copying the PagerTitleStrip code (in your SDK or available online), refactor your fork into your own package, and modify it to suit.` But I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "But I have no idea how to go about doing this" -- what part of "this" are you having difficulty with?

Comment: "refactor your fork into your own package" is the part mostly. Ive copied the PagerTitleStrip into my own file so i can edit already.

Comment: In this case, "refactor" means "move your code from `android.support.v4.view` into your own Java package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just copied the source out of the AOSP and made my own how I liked:

The file can be found in android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4/src/java/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.java

Comment: I get lots of errors when I try to do this. For example here "implements ViewPager.Decor" it says that "The type ViewPager.Decor is not visible". There are also many other errors of this type.

Comment: You need to put it in the package android.support.v4.view and probably change the name of the class.

Comment: Ah brilliant. Thanks so much! You have no idea how long I've been trying this for.

Comment: copying the source would not be a good solution, since updates in new APIs will not be applied to your code. It is better to inherit a new class from PageTitleStrip.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to copy the source - just subclass. See my answer at: [how to change the font of a pagertitlestrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882746/how-to-change-the-font-of-a-pagertitlestrip/17371290#17371290)

Answer (score 5):

if it's a custom font put it in asset folder and change it like this.

```
    PagerTitleStrip _Title = (PagerTitleStrip)rootView.findViewById(R.id.__Weekly_pager_title_strip);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Your font.ttf"); 
    for (int counter = 0 ; counter<_Title.getChildCount(); counter++) {

        if (_Title.getChildAt(counter) instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView)_Title.getChildAt(counter)).setTypeface(font);
            ((TextView)_Title.getChildAt(counter)).setTextSize(25);
        }

    }
```